# Consequence of the Cauchy criterion for series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

The Cauchy Criterion of a series is as follow:

**Theorem:** Let $a_n$ be a real sequence. Then the infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{a_k}$ converges if only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m > n > N$ implies 
$$
 \left| \sum_{k=n+1}^{m}{a_k}  \right| < \varepsilon .
$$

*From this result, how to demonstrate the following corollary?*

**Corollary:** Let $a_n$ be a real sequence. Then the infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{a_k}$ converges if only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ implies 
$$
 \left| \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}{a_k}  \right| < \varepsilon .
$$

Comment: Concluding one direction of the "if and only if" in the Corollary is easy.  Which direction is the easy direction and how would one show that?

Comment: Every Cauchy sequence in a complete metric space such as $\textbf{R}$ is convergent. Conversely, each convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence in a metric space. What concerns you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Cauchy's Theorem, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ imply 
$$
\left| \sum_{k = n + 1}^{n+p}{a_k} \right| < \varepsilon,
$$
for all integer positive $p$. Let $S_{p}^{(n)}$ represent the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{k = n + 1}^{n+p}{a_k}$, when $ n > N $ is fixed. Note that by the *Principle of Mathematical Induction* that $S_{p}^{(n)}$ is true for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, 
$$
\left| \sum_{k = n + 1}^{+\infty}{a_k} \right| < \varepsilon. 
$$

Conversely, let $m, n $ be positive integers such that $m > n > N$. Thus,

$$
\left| \sum_{k = n + 1}^{m}{a_k} \right| \leq \left| \sum_{k = n + 1}^{+\infty}{a_k} \right| < \varepsilon.
$$

Hence, by the Cauchy Criterion, $\sum{a_k}$ converges.